# Summing array values java

Tags: java, math

I'm feeding in an array of length 8 say if trials is 100 it might be of the form 93 5 2 0 0 0 0 0, but whatever the values I have in the array I only get 0.6 back. If anyone can see if I'm making a stupid error that would be great. I've tried it with a for loop but keep getting 0.6.

```
static void getMetric(int[]a, int trials){
    double metric = 0;
    int i =0;
    while(i<8){
        if(i==0){
            double x = (a[0] / trials) - (2 / 15);
            metric += Math.abs(x);
            i++;
        }
        else if(i>0 && i<7){
            double x = (a[i] / trials) - 0.1;
            metric += Math.abs(x);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            double x = (a[7] / trials) - (2 / 15);
            metric += Math.abs(x);
            System.out.println(""+metric);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this method return 0.6 all the time? It doesn't seem to have a return value, so where are you seeing 0.6?

Comment: Sorry I meant it prints 0.6 each time at the print line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need `double`-division and not `int`-division. Remember:

```
int a = 96;
int b = 100;
double c = a / b; //will be 0.0!
```

so the following program should do the same, but more correct, I think (and shorter):

```
static void getMetric(int[] a, int trials){
    double metric = Math.abs((((double)a[0]) / trials) - (2 / 15));

    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        metric += Math.abs((((double)a[i]) / trials) - 0.1);
    }

    metric += Math.abs((((double)a[7]) / trials) - (2 / 15));

    System.out.println(""+metric);
}
```

and that one is even more reable and robust:

```
static void getMetric(int[] a, int trials){
    double metric = calcMetricDiff(a[0], trials, 2.0 / 15.0);

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        metric += calcMetricDiff(a[i], trials, 0.1);
    }   

    metric += calcMetricDiff(a[a.length-1], trials, 2.0 / 15.0);

    System.out.println(""+metric);
}   

private static double calcMetricDiff(double val, int trials, double diff) {
    return Math.abs((val / trials) - diff);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use integer division ( 5 / 3 = 1; 2 / 15 = 0).

So instead of `a[0] / trials`, you should have `a[0] / (double) trials`;

Instead of `2 / 15` you should have `2 / 15.0` etc.

Comment: double x = (double)((a[7] / trials) - (2 / 15)) ?

Comment: Isn't it : a[0] / (double) trials ?

Comment: no, this doesn't work: (double)(2 / 15) == 0.0, because it first does the integer division and then convert to double